# Converting a Microsoft Word document into Flow Document

Tags: wpf, xaml, ms-word, flowdocument

i have a large Microsoft word document , and i would like to copy and paste it into a flow document in WPF4 without losing the font sizing and other issues ..

it's very tough and almost impossible to manually re-arrange the whole document,

So is there any tool that can convert the Microsoft word document into a XAML ready form to directly paste it into the flow document

and thanx so much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can save the Word document as rtf first, then import into a flowdocument would be easy and you shouldn't lose too much formatting.

Comment: Thanx so much for your answering , however i found a nice tool called WORD2XAML that has performed the required functionality .. thanx again ;)